# List of strings, want to split them into two list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to split up a list of strings of file names in a directory. Files were generated in pairs. One is original and the second one is modified. So the list looks something like:

```
files = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data1-m', 'data2-m', 'data3-m']
```

but it is all scrambled up.
I want to create two lists, where indexes are corresponding between each other, like so:

```
original_files = ['data1','data2','data3']
modified_files = ['data1-m','data2-m','data3-m']
```

Currently I have:

```
noised_files = [x for x in files if 'm' in x]
original_files = [x for x in files if not 'm' in x]
```

which does split the list, but it's not pair-wise, where I would like to have:

```
>original_files[0] = 'data1'
>noised_files[0] = 'data1-m'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that every element in the list has its "partner" present?

Comment: Yes, definetely. Length of a list is always an odd number.

Comment: Did you mean even? :)

Comment: You only need one iteration, not two!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh "but it is all scrambled up". I don't think it's guaranteed that if `data1` precedes `data2`, then `data1-m` precedes `data2-m`.

Comment: Good point1 I will sort both the lists then! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorting (O(n lg n)) is worse than two O(n) iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `list-comprehension` with `str.endswith()` and `sorted()`:

```
files = ['data3', 'data1', 'data2', 'data2-m', 'data3-m', 'data1-m']

files = sorted(files)
print([x for x in files if x.endswith('m')])
print([x for x in files if not x.endswith('m')])
```

**EDIT**:

Which can also be written like:

```
noised_files = [x for x in files if x.endswith('m')]
original_files = [x for x in files if x not in noised_files]

print(original_files[0])                 # data1
print(noised_files[0])                   # data1-m
```

**EDIT 2**:

Using `filter()`:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('m'), files)))
print(list(filter(lambda x: not x.endswith('m'), files)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['data1-m', 'data2-m', 'data3-m']
['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that all the partners are present in the original list, you can just "ignore" the `-m` variants and "re-add" them to the new list.

```
pairs = [(x, "{}-m".format(x)) for x in files if not x.endswith("-m")]
```

Then you can unzip `pairs` to get your two corresponding lists if necessary:

```
original_files, modified_files = zip(*pairs)
```

This maintains the order of the original files, while re-ording the modified files to match.

Comment: this is indeed the best...  think about it, no `sort`, `strip`, `groupby` are being performed, which means it will be fast and memory-efficient.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be grouping the strings in the list using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), and using `zip`. This way you ensure that the elements sharing the starting substring in both lists have matching indices:

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [list(v) for _,v in groupby(sorted(files), key=lambda x: x.rstrip('-m'))]
original_files, noised_files= list(zip(*l))
```

Which gives:

```
print(original_files)
# ('data1', 'data2', 'data3')

print(noised_files)
# ('data1-m', 'data2-m', 'data3-m')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need two list comprehensions, when you can do it in one iteration.
I will also sort the list before hand to take care of scrambled lists like 
`['data1', 'data3', 'data2-m', 'data1', 'data1-m', 'data3-m']`

```
files = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data1-m', 'data2-m', 'data3-m']
noised_files = []
original_files = []

for file in sorted(files):
    if file.endswith('-m'):
        noised_files.append(file)
    else:
        original_files.append(file)
print(noised_files)
print(original_files)
#['data1-m', 'data2-m', 'data3-m']
#['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
```

Comment: why not `for file in sorted(files)` instead of sorting during printing?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be safer to use regex. Your files might contain the letter `m` in the name, so you are looking for files ending in `-m`. I recommend something like this:

```
import re

files = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data1-m', 'data2-m', 'data3-m']

original_files = []
modified_files = []

for file in files:
    if (re.search("-m$", file)):
        modified_files.append(file)
    else:
        original_files.append(file)

print(original_files, modified_files)
```

You can sort the lists at the end, before printing or write more code to compare them.

Comment: Regular expression matching is overkill, since you just need to match a fixed suffix. Use `if file.endswith("-m")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the part of the name that signals modified files is always at the same place in the name, you can simply sort the lists you obtained:

```
files = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data3-m', 'data1-m', 'data3-m']

# we could use list comprehensions, but this way, we only iterate once on files. 
original_files = []
modified_files = []
for f in files:  
    if f.endswith('-m'):
        modified_files.append(f)
    else:
        original_files.append(f)

original_files.sort()
modified_files.sort()
```

Output:

```
for i in range(len(original_files)):
    print(original_files[i], modified_files[i])

# data1 data1-m
# data2 data3-m
# data3 data3-m
```